# How to install new packages for common lisp without asdf-install

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I am new to cl, and I just learned to install packages using asdf-install, but I don't know how it works, I wonder how the package can be installed manully, then I could understand the use of the files in the root directory of the source code, thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer: Just use [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/).

Long answer: if you want to understand, how the package, or - more precisely - ASDF system, is laid out, that's a good idea. Actually, there's nothing hard about that.

Every ASDF system should have a system definition file with `.asd` extension. This file names other file of the system with their paths relative to the .asd file, their types (by default: lisp source code) and dependencies. Your Lisp should know where to find the system definition file. In ASDF there are 2 ways to inform Lisp about it: adding the directory, in which you store the file or symlink to it, to `asdf:*central-registry*` list or setting up special configuration files (called source-registry - more on that in [ASDF manual](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Configuring-ASDF.html)).

Now if you want to install the system by hand, just download its sources, extract them into some directory (like in `/home/user/lib/lisp/` - you may get `/home/user/lib/lisp/cl-ppcre-2.3.1/`, inside which there's `cl-ppcre.asd`). To let your Lisp find out about it just `(push "/home/user/lib/lisp/cl-ppcre-2.3.1/" asdf:*central-registry*)` (and don't forget the trailing slash - it's required), and then you can load the system with `(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :cl-ppcre)`.

You might also setup a special dir, where you'll symlink your existing systems, like `/home/user/.lisp/` and add it to `*central-registry*` at Lisp startup type (e.g. in `.sbclrc`). Now if you want to temporarily override some of the system linked in this dir, say, with a newer version, you don't need to unlink anything - just push the path to alternative system to `*central-registry*`.

Quicklisp does all that for you and more...